# What does this icon near SteamPlay text mean?

Tags: steam, steam-play

[image: The Icon]
I saw this icon while browsing on steam and I wonder what it means. What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the logo of the VR company Oculus, it means that you can play that game on the Oculus Rift. If you open the page of that game, it shows more details such as the inputs it accepts and the recommended play area on the sidebar:

[image: VR Support description]

Also, if it were to support the HTC Vive, it'd look like this:

[image: HTC Vive logo on Tabletop Simulator]